# M1 - find orphaned simple non visible products

Tags: simple-product

I need to find/identify non-visible simple products that are missing the link to their configurable parent

query logic is supposed to be

products in `catalog_product_entity` & `catalog_product_entity_int` (not visible & enabled) but not in `catalog_product_super_link`

The following gives me no results which isnt right (an attempt at editing an existing query)

```
select
A.sku
FROM
catalog_product_entity A
INNER JOIN
catalog_product_entity_int B
ON A.`entity_id` = B.`entity_id`
WHERE
A.type_id = 'simple' AND 
(( B.`attribute_id`='102' AND B.`value`='1') ## product is not visible
AND 
(B.`attribute_id`='96' AND B.`value`='1')) ## product is enabled
AND(
B.`entity_id` NOT IN(
SELECT DISTINCT
(`product_id`)
FROM
`catalog_product_super_link`
)    )
```